# using powershell invoke-expression to run code output

Tags: powershell

I have been doing a lot of reading on invoke-expression (also known as iex) and I'm having trouble getting it to work for me.

My understanding is, it will run any powershell code you give to it.  However, when I run my tests on it, it does not run the code.

**Example:**

```
## testcode.ps1

$myvar = "i am here"
if ($myvar -ne $null) {
    "($myvar) variable is Full"
} else {
    "($myvar) variable is Empty"
}
```

Now, if I cat(gc) this file and I pass it to `iex`, it outputs a bunch of errors. Same thing happens when I save the code into a variable and then feed the variable to `iex`.  Neither works.

Despite the fact that I've tried numerous examples, I feel there's something minor I'm doing wrong that I'm hoping someone can point out for me.

I'm new to Windows scripting, so please bear with me. These are the results of the tests I performed:

**First Test:**

```
PS C:\Users\J> gc C:\Users\J\testcode.ps1 | iex
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:31
+ cat C:\Users\J\testcode.ps1 | iex    
+                               ~~~    
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:PSObject) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException   
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
iex : At line:1 char:23
+ if ($myvar -ne $null) {
+                       ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:1 char:31
+ cat C:\Users\J\testcode.ps1 | iex
+                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

**Second Test:**

```
PS C:\Users\J> $scriptBlock = gc C:\Users\J\testcode.ps1
PS C:\Users\J> 
PS C:\Users\J> iex -Command "$scriptBlock"
iex : At line:1 char:23
+  $myvar = "i am here" if ($myvar -ne $null) {     "($myvar) variable  ...
+                       ~~
Unexpected token 'if' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:1
+ iex -Command "$scriptBlock"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

PS C:\Users\J>
```

I'm aware that I can just run the file containing the code. However, I need help figuring out how `iex` works and what it is I'm doing wrong.

Please kindly advise.

Comment: Well the file running the code won't work with `Get-Content` since it goes line by line without separators when put like that. The script also won't receive output into a pipeline since you only wrote the output to the host instead of returning it. Use `return "($myvar) variable is Full"` and the other one. you can use `Get-Content` if you use a `foreach` loop and add each line to a variable separated by a newline to a variable that you then converted to a script block

Comment: thanks for the comment.  but i have no idea how to do the for loop part you mentioned.  seems like a roundabout way though.  @Bill_Stewart suggestion looks promising but fails for me.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart i tried `[scriptblock]::Create("$scriptBlock") | iex` and i still get errors.  I tried it without the quotes a well and it still failed.

Comment: As @mklement0's answer demonstrates, `Get-Content`'s `-raw` switch will read the whole file instead of line by line like I stated in my comment.

Comment: Thanks, @NekoMusume, but note that `return` is never _necessary_: any statement whose output is neither captured nor redirected is _implicitly_ output (returned) to the _success output stream_, which by default prints to the host (console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:

**`Invoke-Expression` should generally be *avoided* and used only as a *last resort***, due to its security risks. In short: avoid it, if possible, given that superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

For the record: in the case at hand, the superior alternative is to *directly invoke* the script file:

```
# Prepend `& `, if the script file path is quoted or references a variable.
C:\Users\J\testcode.ps1
```

---

`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) accepts *multiple* strings *via the pipeline*, and evaluates *each* individually, as a self-contained script.
Therefore, **you must provide the contents of your script *as a whole*, as a *single string***, which is what `Get-Content`'s (`gc`'s) `-Raw` switch does<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
Get-Content -Raw C:\Users\J\testcode.ps1 | Invoke-Expression
```

Alternatively, pass the script-file contents as an *argument*:

```
Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Raw C:\Users\J\testcode.ps1)
```

Note that passing the string to evaluate *as an argument* truly only accepts a *single* string, so the command would *fail* without `-Raw`.

---

<sup>[1] By default, the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) cmdlet reads a file *line by line*, passing each line through the pipeline as it is being read.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
$myvar = "I'm Here"

#Using Invoke-Expression - Accepts a STRING as Input

$SBCode = 'if ($Null -ne $myvar) {"($myvar) variable is Full"}' +
          'else {"`$myvar variable is Empty"}'

Clear-Host
"Before Invoke-Expression `$myvar = $myvar"

$Result = Invoke-Expression  $SBCode

"Invoke-Expression Returns: $Result"

#Using Invoke-Command - Accepts Script Block as Input

$SBCode = {
   if ($myvar -ne $null) {
     "($myvar) variable is Full"
   } 
   else {
    "`$myvar variable is Empty"
   }
} #End $SBCode Script Block

"Before Invoke-Command `$myvar = $myvar"

$Result = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $SBCode

"Invoke-Command Returns: $Result"
```

Results:

```
Before Invoke-Expression $myvar = I'm Here
Invoke-Expression Returns: (I'm Here) variable is Full
Before Invoke-Command $myvar = I'm Here
Invoke-Command Returns: (I'm Here) variable is Full

# After changing $MyVar = $Null

Before Invoke-Expression $myvar = 
Invoke-Expression Returns: $myvar variable is Empty
Before Invoke-Command $myvar = 
Invoke-Command Returns: $myvar variable is Empty
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use [out-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.3) to convert output into string.

`cat C:\Users\J\testcode.ps1 | out-string | Invoke-Expression`